# Kotlin (Ktor) request class for multipart form data

Tags: kotlin, multipartform-data, ktor

I want to create a request class that collects all the parts (files and items) and validate it, something similar to the example I put (below) with the json requests.

**REQUEST JSON SERIALIZABLE EXAMPLE CLASS**

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
class CreateGroupRequest(
    val name: String,
    val description: String? = null,
    val visibility: String? = "PUBLIC"
)
```

**HANDLE JSON REQUEST EXAMPLE**

```
route("create") {
                post {
                    val request = call.receive<CreateGroupRequest>()
                    try {
                        //CODE
                        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    } catch (e: SharedDomainException) {
                        call.respond(HttpStatusCode(e.errorCode, e.errorMessage))
                    }
                }
            }
```

What I mean, for example, is that in this case I want to change it because the groups also has a profile photo that I want to upload or in other cases,  posts domain has text, author and a multiple images.

I have read this [stackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823689/check-whether-all-parameter-exist-or-not-in-multipart-request-body-with-ktor) but I can't see how I can make a general class to read the multipart requests without having to duplicate code in each handler.

**So, does anyone know how I can read the request multipart-form-data body in a shared class and validate it with kotlin/ktor?**

Comment: You can move all the code that needs to be reused from the post you are referring to to a separate function/extension.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov 
Not quite. From what I understand from the answer I have attached, the reading of the multipart-form-data is specific to the situation. How can I make a generic class that reads the multipart and puts it in a request class?

In the JSON example case, the serializable parses the request and puts it in a class. Is it possible to do something similar? How can I build the serializable for multipart?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this example writes data to a file. I'm not quite sure how you expect to parse the class from it? Either way, you can take out some of the data reading part and then process the data as you wish. Are you sending a huge JSON that you want to parse later? Add some pseudocode of how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, you can use the [ContentNegotiation](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html) and [register a content converter](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html#register_converter) for the `multipart/form-data` Content-type. In the `convertForReceive` method you can use [CIOMultipartDataBase](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-http/ktor-http-cio/ktor-http-cio/io.ktor.http.cio/-c-i-o-multipart-data-base/index.html) to parse multipart data and then [deserialize](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-contextual-serializer/deserialize.html) it using [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library. For `deserialize` method call you need to provide [a decoder](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization.encoding/-decoder/index.html) for the `MultiPartData` objects, which you need to implement.

The above approach will work but is very inefficient for parts with a large binary body because parts in an HTTP message go one after another so all of them will be eagerly read into memory.

Comment: Hi, I'm programming the converter but I can't get the arguments of KType... It seems that serializer gets the arguments like val request = context.subject // val typeInfo = request.typeInfo // and val arguments = typeInfo.arguments but in my custom converter typeInfo is a Ktype (my request class) but when I get the arguments always are empty.

Does you know how to get arguments of KType?

Comment: Here https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/8041500b501ed90f7f0132675d632009 is a working example.